# Why container and codec has different time base?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, pts

I used ffmpeg to get video info. The output is

```
  Duration: 00:05:57.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 611 kb/s Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 808x610, 609 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
```

The time base is used to somehow (this is also my another question) calculate when to decode and show the frame, right? So whose time base is used, container (12800) or codec (50)?

The another question is why tbn=12800 and not 90000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct, both are different.

The tbn is a function of the encoder creating the stream. So for a 10 fps stream, it can be 90000, which implies 90000 ticks a second, giving you 9000 ticks per frame. It can also simply be 10, which implies 1 tick per frame (for the same 10 fps stream).

90000 is commonly used at streaming level (TS streaming comes to mind), but encoders are not bound by this. This (tbn) is something decoders will use, not the application systems which use container data.

If you have a container, you should use the container time base and time stamps because it is normalized across all streams in the container. You will use parameters like tbn only inside a codec decoder.

Comment: What does "ticks per frame" means? For what the codec will use it?

Comment: The codec decoder uses it for knowing the time lag between frames. In some codecs it is used for motion vector scaling. If you are not working inside a codec all you need to know is that it is a simple way to keeping tracking of how many frames a second. So to achieve 29.97 fps, one second is considered to have 30000 ticks and frames are 1001 ticks apart. Ticks is imaginary. Timestamps per frame will therefore increment by 1001 per frame. If you are not working inside a codec, you needn't really worry about this. Use the container data for the system.

Comment: Codec and container time base must be consistent - container timescale must be  equal or greater than codec timescale, and container timescale must be dividable completely by codec timescale, right?